The generator of analytic semigroup
Definition: Let $0<\omega<\frac{\pi}{2}$. A family of bounded operators $\{S(z):z\in S^0_{\omega_{+}}\}$ on $X$ is called a holomorphic semigroup if

$S(z)S(\omega)=S(z+\omega) $ for all $z,\omega\in S^0_{\omega_{+}}$,

$S(z)$ is holomorphic on $S^0_{\omega_{+}}$
Let $T$ be the generator of $\{S(z)\}$, namely the operator in $X$ such that
$Tu=\lim_{t\rightarrow} \cfrac{S(t)u-u}{t}$


with domain consisting of all $u\in X$ for which the limit exists. Then $-T$ is an operator of type $S^0_{(\frac{\pi}{2}-\omega)_{+}}$ in $X$.
Now I want to prove the question as follow:
$\forall f \in \{f(z) \in H(S^0_{(\frac{\pi}{2}-\mu)_{+}}): \exists s>0,such\,\,  that \,|f(z)|<\frac{|z|^s}{(1+|z|)^{2s}}\},\mu<\omega$, where $H(S^0_{(\frac{\pi}{2}-\mu)_{+}})$ denotes the set of all holomorphic functions on $S^0_{(\frac{\pi}{2}-\mu)_{+}}$ .
then by McINTOSH we get
$f(T)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\delta}(T-\lambda I)^{-1}f(\lambda)d\lambda$ where the contour $\delta=\delta_+\bigcup\delta_-$ is given by $\delta_\pm=\pm te^{\pm i v}$ for $\pm t\geq 0$.
But I don't know how to get the representation about the $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}=\int_{\Gamma_+}e^{\lambda z}e^{-z T}dz$, where $\lambda\in \delta_+.$
